# Cross domain request using jsonp: from https to http

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, https, jsonp

I have following problem: I need to send some data from page on my site (https://test.com) to another one (for example http://anotherdomain.com). User just enters data to the text box and clicks a button. Script on this page will handle click event and send GET request (using jQuery ajax method) to the http://anotherdomain.com.

```
var enteredValue = $('#MytextBox').val();

function jsonpCallbackFunc(data) 
{
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://anotherdomain.com/qwerty/ajaxpage.php',
    data: { valuefield: enteredValue },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallbackFunc',
    success: function (json) {
          // some code
    }
})
```

I received next error using FireFox - "Blocked loading mixed active content http://anotherdomain.com/qwerty/ajaxpage.php...".
The same situation for IE9 and Chrome.

Question: how can we resolve this issue? Can we just allow this script for only one site or maybe we can use another piece of code (not jQuery+jsonp)?

Thank you in advance for the help.

P.S. From "http"-site this code works as expected.

Update:
We resolved the issue using another "https"-url (https://anotherdomain.com/qwerty/ajaxpage.php). We had tried use it before, but it had untrusted certificate. Now it works correctly. Thank you for the help and advice.

Comment: Use a script on your server to fetch the external JSON data and return it locally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about incorrect url and untrusted certificate.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to **CORS**. When you request to other domain, a preflight request may happen on condition for the *ajax* calls. You are using jQuery and hence custom header will set in your request. So use

> Access-Control-Request-Headers
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Please refer [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and its [implementation](http://blog.mozilla.org/services/2013/02/04/implementing-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-cornice/).

Answer (score 1):

This should also need to be allowed in server, try to add this where you process your request

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

Hope this may help

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I don't have an access to the code on http://anotherdomain.com.

Comment: Refer this - http://enable-cors.org/index.html hope this may provide you lot of understanding about cross domain requests.